I need to change the number of columns and rows in the terminal for my graphic library
I have been developing a graphic library for generating 2d graphics on the terminal.  I need to control the number of rows and columns to specify the resolution, I want to know if there is an option to handle this and make the application portable to the terminals so I don't have to implement opengl.
I have tried with Gtk and Qt terminal emulators but I didn't succeed.

If you want portable code for manipulating the terminal, you should look at the ncurses library.

How do you open the terminal? And please stick to only one language.

You can use cairo multi-platform library for 2D graphics. Resolution of drawing area and its control depends on chosen framework (it can be used directly within X11/Xorg backends or in scopes of GTK for example).

I don't know if this is general enough, but it works for xterm.
This works because xterm exports its window ID to the environment as WINDOWID.
We can use this value in XGetWindowAttributes and XResizeWindow calls.

The width/height is in pixels and not character row/columns.

If the window has scrollbars, etc. I don't know if the geometry includes these or not.

If the geometry isn't divisible by the font width/height in use, xterm will adjust to only allow a width/height that is an exact multiple of the font width/height (a good thing).

xterm will adjust the geometry via termios, so that a subprogram will be able to get the character geometry via tcgetattr

Foreground and background colors can be changed via escape codes sent to stdout.

However, AFAICT, its difficult to determine or change the font. Or, window decorations.



Note: there probably are better ways, but ...
I was able to change the xterm geometry using the following. Note that this is just a demo and has no error checking:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    char *cp = getenv("WINDOWID");
    if (cp == NULL) {
        printf("No WINDOWID\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    long xid = atoll(cp);
    printf("xid=%ld\n",xid);

    XWindowAttributes attr;

    XGetWindowAttributes(dpy,xid,&attr);
    printf("OLD: width=%d height=%d\n",attr.width,attr.height);

    int termfd = 1;

    struct winsize ws;
    ioctl(termfd,TIOCGWINSZ,&ws);
    printf("CHAR: rows=%d cols=%d\n",ws.ws_row,ws.ws_col);

    int wid = -1;
    int hgt = -1;

    if (argc > 0) {
        wid = atoi(*argv++);
        --argc;
    }

    if (argc > 0) {
        hgt = atoi(*argv++);
        --argc;
    }

    printf("ARG: width=%d height=%d\n",wid,hgt);
    int chg = (wid > 0) || (hgt > 0);

    if (wid < 0)
        wid = attr.width;
    if (hgt < 0)
        hgt = attr.height;

    if (chg) {
        printf("CHG: width=%d height=%d\n",wid,hgt);
        XResizeWindow(dpy,xid,wid,hgt);
        //XFlush(dpy);
        XSync(dpy,0);
    }

    // a hack: give xterm time to change window character size
    struct winsize ws2;
    for (int iter = 1;  iter <= 10000;  ++iter) {
        ioctl(termfd,TIOCGWINSZ,&ws2);
        if (! chg)
            break;
        if (ws2.ws_row != ws.ws_row)
            break;
        if (ws2.ws_col != ws.ws_col)
            break;
    }

    XGetWindowAttributes(dpy,xid,&attr);
    printf("NEW: width=%d height=%d\n",attr.width,attr.height);

    printf("CHAR: rows=%d cols=%d\n",ws2.ws_row,ws2.ws_col);

    XCloseDisplay(dpy);

    return 0;
}


It might be easier to invoke xterm as a subprogram (and run the target program within that):
xterm [options] -e myprogram

xterm has many command line options to control character geometry, font, scrollbars, decorations, colors, etc.
